# Zend framework Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Albums' not found in

Tags: zend-framework, classnotfound

I am trying to learn Zend framework from "Getting Started with Zend Framework" By Rob Allen. I have used the same example that has been given, but getting the error -

> Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Albums' not found in /var/www/html/workbench/sreekantk/zf-tutorial/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 14 .

I think I have to set path to models folder, but don't know how to do it. Could anyone please help me out of this.

This is my `Bootstrap.php` file.

> // application/Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
    {
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH.'/application/modules'));
        return $autoloader;
    }

}
```

---

Thanks Just H. It worked. Actually I changed the folder structure and after the again added `appnamespace="Application"` to the `application.ini` file. Thanks you all for your comments.

Comment: Could you let us know the folder structure of where your model Class file is, and how you have setup autoloading for your models.

Comment: Have you pasted the "Zend Library" to /library folder of your application...?

Comment: Perhaps check your application.ini.  I think you want to have the following set:  `appnamespace = Application` and then make sure your models are in the `application/models` directory.

Comment: @Just H: I have done that too.

Comment: @Chris : I have included my Bootstrap file.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you get to the controller your primary setup seems to be fine. So, if you have the class in a separate file the problem is probably a simple typo somewhere.

a) with all the following, look out for lower/upper case
b) note that the models folder is **plural** whereas the class is Model **singular**
c) make sure the class is named Application_**Model**_DbTable_Albums
d) make sure the file is named `Albums.php` and in a folder named `application/models/DbTable`

Good luck learning ZF

Comment: Checked them all. But still I am getting the same error. Do I have to set the path to models somewhere, like we have done for controllers in application.ini file.

Comment: The only thing required would be the `appnamespace = "Application"` in the application.ini as your default namespace. I dunno your learning example but that _should_ be covered. From that point on the autoloader should take over. Again, make sure you have no typos. Just yesterday I wasted a couple hours because of some typo. The error is pretty simple: The class cannot be found and this is usually some path or naming problem!

Comment: I've just noticed that in your bootstrap example you write **modules**. If that was specifically for your DbTable--that would be a typo because your DB table is in **models**!!! So, make sure you have your DBTable in models and not modules.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.9.2, the default module will automatically initialise an autoloader for the namespace configured in `appnamespace` (defaults to "Application" on a vanilla install). You can remove your `_initAutoload()` method.

So long as your class exists in `application/models/DbTable/Albums.php` and is named `Application_Model_DbTable_Albums`, it should be able to autoload the class on first use.

Be mindful of path case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same tutorial and what Adrian World said on Aug 9'11 at 13:26 helped me get rid of the error. My Bootstrap now is:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH.'/application/models'));
        return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

Where the only thing that changed was going from **modules** to **models**

Answer (score 0):

You should define Bootstrap class of the current Module. Then it will be fine.